# Creating a horizontal auto-scrolling row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How should I go about creating a div box with some content in it, for example look at link, that slides automatically to next content(as indicated by arrows in picture) I understand I'll probably need jquery for this but is there another way of doing it(just wondering)

oi62.tinypic.com(SLASH)1565npw.jpg

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

yes you are alright you need JQuery or JavaScript code pure , for create this slider because  relations between your DIVs that's mean your DIVs should be a variables for create relations between theme for work ( Next and Prev ) correctly , you will need a interactive programming language but don't worry  there's a lot of *Jquery simple plugin* , free and open source will fit your need .(Just googled JQuery Slider)

there's a solution with CSS3 but you will not able to use Next And Prev , just slide move in circle infinite but it's not a **functional solution** .
I hope that's answer will help you .